# Friend with a certain template class : "template<ANY...> friend class A;"

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, friend

Is there a way to declare friend with a template class in a wildcard way?

### Example

I always declare friend like this :-

```
//B.h
template<class T1,class T2>class B{}; 
//C.h
class C{                              
    template<class,class> friend class B;
};
```

However, if `B` template argument is changed, I will have to updated `C` which is usually a far-separated header.

```
//B.h
template<int T3,class T1,class T2>class B{}; 
//C.h
class C{                              
    template<int,class,class> friend class B;  //<-- manually update here too
};
```

It causes minor maintainability problem. (For me, once every week.)

### Question

Can I do something like this?

```
class C{                              
    template<ANY...> friend class B; 
};
```

Is it just impossible?

I faintly feel that this question might be duplicated, because it is probably a common issue.
However, I can't find one.

Comment: are you referring to [variadic class template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template)?

Comment: @codekaizer  Yes.  I also tried it.  It works only in some situation.

Comment: @codeKaizer still OP need to instantiate with what he needed in respective class "C"

Comment: If you have to change the template parameters for B often, maybe you should consider templating it with a variadic parameter pack?  That would probably generalize your code better, and it will be friend-able easily with a `template <typename... Args> friend class B`, if you want to access particular types in the parameter pack you can do `std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Args...>>`, this can be made into an alias for easier usage.  `template <int Index> using TypeAtIndex = std::tuple_element<Index, std::tuple<Args...>>`

Comment: @Curious It is a desperate measure.  I think it is not worth in my case, but thank.

Comment: @Curious how would that handle a mix of type and value template parameters?

Comment: @KinanAlSarmini I was thinking a layer of `std::integral_constant` indirection would do fine

Comment: @javaLover Are macros out of the question?

Comment: @Kinan Al Sarmini  Haha, another desperate measure. Actually, it might be a good solution that I tried too hard to not think about (because it is a hack), thank!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
// declare the concept of a variadic B
template<class...Ts> struct B;


struct C
{
    private:

    // any B with any number of Types is a friend
    template<class...Ts> friend struct B;

    void privateThing() {};
};


// now specialise B <T1, T2>
template<class T1, class T2> struct B<T1, T2> {

    void foo(C& c) {
        c.privateThing();
    }

};

int main()
{
    C c;
    B<int, double> b;
    b.foo(c);
}
```

Comment: I can't make it work for `B<int,class,class>`. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f909942d192f39e   Did I miss something?   (Thank for the answer. It would be handy in some other cases.)

Comment: @javaLover Unfortunetly non-type template parameters cannot be treated like type ones. I don't think you'll find a workaround there...

Comment: @W.F.    That will help me stop wasting time searching, thank!  If you are sure enough, you can post as another solution. XD

Comment: @javaLover I'll try but I'm not sure if I'm gonna make it as I don't have too much time today (and the *can't* answers always take much more time than the workaround ones:))

Comment: You can turn a non type into a type with std::integral_value<>